# ActionMailer can I have an html and plain text partial with same name but different extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, naming-conventions, actionmailer, partials

For each ActionMailer email view I have an html and text file, like so:

```
new_user_welcome.html.haml
new_user_welcome.txt.haml
```

Using this convention, ActionMailer automatically handles sending html and plain text emails for me.

Can I do this with email partials too, to get a html and txt version of the same partial? For example, can I name my email footer partials like this, and will ActionMailer automatically use the right one used in the html and text emails?

```
_email_footer.html.haml
_email_footer.txt.haml
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have partials for your mails too:

> _email_header.html.erb
>
> _email_footer.html.erb

Then you can refer to them inside each of your emails:

```
<%= render :partial => 'email_header' %>
... Email body here...
<%= render :partial => 'email_footer' %>
```

Repeat the process for txt emails partials.

Comment: I know that. What I'm asking is if I can have html and txt versions of the same partial.